# Where do I have to search for a specific Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I want to catch a Bagon (*Kindwurm*) and watched for its habitats in the Pokédex:

[image: kindwurm pokedex]

The Meteor Falls are shown as a habitat, but now I wonder what the different pictures mean. I guess the third one for example symbolizes that it can only be caught in water, but I can't find a decent description what the three pictures describe.

Comment: Try the edge of a cliff, buh-bye... (couldn't resist that, lol).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first picture means that you find the Pokemon by walking around in that area. In outdoors areas, this means tall grass. Indoors, it means just walking around (like in a cave).

The second picture indicates whether or not you can find the Pokemon via surfing.

The third picture indicates whether or not you can find the Pokemon via fishing.

Answer (score 3):

The three images represent respectively walking, surfing, and fishing.

Answer (score 0):

For the very specific case of Bagon, IIRC, there is only one specific room within Meteor Falls that you can encounter wild Bagon while walking within. I believe it is the room you need Waterfall to access, and contains the Draco Meteor TM.